# Laravel schema builder primary key as foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the Laravel 4.2 schema builder to create some tables referencing each other, and am having some issues.

I have a simplified ERD. Note that only relevant columns are shown:

[image: ERD]

Note that I cannot modify the `tblcurrencies` and `tbldomains` tables in any way, since I am developing a module to hook into an existing system.

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. The `extensions` table contains extra information about rows in the `tbldomains` table
2. The `prices` table contains pricing information about a domain in a certain currency, with the additional type value (registration, renewal, transfer)
3. I want to use foreign keys so that I can cascade deletions.

Currently, I use the following code to create the two tables:

```
Capsule::schema()->create('extensions', function ($table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->integer('relid', 10);
    // ...
    $table->primary(['relid']);
    $table->foreign('relid')->references('id')->on('tbldomains')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Capsule::schema()->create('prices', function ($table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->integer('relid', 10);
    $table->integer('currency', 10);
    $table->enum('type', ['domainregister', 'domainrenew', 'domaintransfer']);
    // ...
    $table->primary(['relid', 'currency', 'type']);
    $table->foreign('relid')->references('relid')->on('extensions')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('currency')->references('id')->on('tblcurrencies')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

The creation script for the `prices` table results in the following SQL query:

```
create table `prices` (`relid` int unsigned null auto_increment primary key, `currency` int unsigned null auto_increment primary key, `type` enum('domainregister', 'domainrenew', 'domaintransfer') not null, ...) engine = InnoDB
```

Which in turn results in the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

I have also tried setting the primary keys as unique instead, figuring that perhaps Laravel automatically set primary integer keys as auto increment.

Furthermore, I tried setting the columns as `unsigned` and `index`, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27977410/4385713) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23966573/4385713) answer

**How do I stop the schema builder from setting the `relid` and `currency` fields to auto increment, since they are simply foreign keys?**

Answer (score 0):

based on Laravel Documentation Api on the below link, only `string()` method can have length attribute.
[Laravel Documentation Api](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html)

So to make those two column `unsigned` and not `primary key` or `auto increment` make the following change:

from this:

```
$table->integer('relid', 10);
$table->integer('currency', 10);
```

to this:

```
$table->integer('relid', false, true);
$table->integer('currency', false, true);
```

---

Because as per the documentation the `integer()` method syntax is:

```
integer(string $column, bool $autoIncrement = false, bool $unsigned = false)
```

And what you did is you assigned a value (10) to a boolean variable ($autoIncrement) which will always returns true on this case. For further proof of this, please refer back to the below link from php.net.
[php.net Boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

I had the same issue before, and when I start referring back Laravel documentation 90% of confusion will be cleared. Hope this helps you.

---

Note: you can also use `unsignedInteger()` method, which i think it's more explicit and easier to remember:

```
unsignedInteger(string $column, bool $autoIncrement = false)
```

So the code will be like so:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('relid');
$table->unsignedInteger('currency');
```